# Why is $ allowed but $$, or <$> disallowed as an operator (FS0035) and what makes $ special?

Tags: f#, operator-overloading, dollar-sign

`$` is allowed in a custom operator, but if you try to use `$$`, `<$>` or for instance `~$%` as operator name you will receive the following error:

> error FS0035: This construct is deprecated: '$' is not permitted as a character in operator names and is reserved for future use

`$` clearly **also has the '$' in the name**, but works, why?
I.e.:

```
let inline ( $ ) f y = f y

// using it works just fine:
let test = 
    let add x = x + 1
    add $ 12
```

I see `$` a lot in online examples and apparently as a particular kind of operator. What is this spcial treatment or role for `$` (i.e. in Haskell or OCaml) and what should `<$>` do if it were allowed (edit)?

Trying to fool the system by creating a function like `op_DollarDollar`, doesn't fly, syntax check is done on the call site as well. Though as an example, this trick does work with other (legal) operators:

```
// works
let inline op_BarQmark f y = f y
let test = 
    let add x = x + 1
    add |? 12

// also works:
let inline op_Dollar f y = f y
let test = 
    let add x = seq { yield x + 1 }
    add $ 12
```

Comment: Yes, it's a same we can't define the standard ``<$>`` operator in F#. We should submit a request to allow these operators.

Comment: `:` is also on the list. [`$`](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/6afc4f9776a5dba903ca6b11965a206fb8bc23d8/src/fsharp/lex.fsl#L117) and [`:`](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/6afc4f9776a5dba903ca6b11965a206fb8bc23d8/src/fsharp/lex.fsl#L115)

Comment: @guy, for `:` I understand it somewhat, since `:>` and `:?>` should probably not be overridable. I could say the same for `::`, but since `@` is overridable and `..` is too (surprising, but true), I would only assume `::` isn't because of the colon-related protected operators.

Comment: @guy, what is the "standard" `<$>` operator, what standard?

Comment: This is a question I am waiting for [kvb](http://stackoverflow.com/users/82959/kvb) to answer

Comment: In Haskell, `<$>` is an infix synonym for `fmap`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann yes, also in other languages and it would be nice to be able to define it in F#. In [FSharpPlus](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus/blob/590ef4d0b1b843141f62b9d951e3b9fdb044d771/FSharpPlus/Operators.fs#L35) and other libraries it was defined like ``<!>`` due of this limitation.

Comment: @GuyCoder - your wish is my command :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's some inconsistency in the [F# specification](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf) around this point.  Section 3.7 of the F# spec defines symbolic operators as

> ```
> regexp first-op-char = !%&*+-./<=>@^|~ 
> regexp op-char       = first-op-char | ? 
>
> token quote-op-left  =
>     |  <@ <@@  
>
> token quote-op-right  =
>     |  @> @@>  
>
> token symbolic-op  =
>     | ?
>     | ?<-
>     | first-op-char op-char*
>     | quote-op-left
>     | quote-op-right
> ```

(and `$` also doesn't appear as a symbolic keyword in section 3.6), which would indicate that it's wrong for the compiler to accept `( $ )` as an operator.

However, section 4.4 (which covers operator precedence) includes these definitions:

> ```
> infix-or-prefix-op :=
>     +,  -, +., -., %, &, && 
>
> prefix-op :=
>     infix-or-prefix-op
>     ~ ~~ ~~~             (and any repetitions of ~)
>     !OP                  (except !=) 
>
> infix-op :=
>     infix-or-prefix-op  
>     -OP +OP || <OP >OP = |OP &OP ^OP *OP /OP %OP !=  
>                          (or any of these preceded by one or more ‘.’) 
>     := 
>     :: 
>     $ 
>     or 
>     ?
> ```

and the following table of precedence and associativity does contain `$` (but no indication that `$` can appear as one character in any longer symbolic operator).  Consider filing a bug so that the spec can be made consistent one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks. I knew you would have a definitive answer.

Comment: Have a nice holiday. :)